# Selecting last 5 minutes record - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Please i want to select from mysql database the last 5 minute record

Which means if the the datefeild between the last 5 minutes the engine will select it

Any hints please for that??

Regards

Answer (score 15):

You could do like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
FROM `table`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND NOW()
```

Comment: I use 'where timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)' but same thing really. Yours is easier to understand logically though

Comment: If you store the the timestamp at UTC and your client is in other timezone, you should replace `NOW()` with `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`
For example: ```WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND UTC_TIMESTAMP()```